# My app Is Incompatible with android 6 marshmallow device

Tags: android, compatibility, android-6.0-marshmallow

I cannot see my application after upgrading to android 6. This is my manifest and gradle file. With Lollipop works fine, but 6 and later tells me that it is not compatible.I have also tried with `buildToolsVersion 23` but the same

```
android {
compileSdkVersion 23
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"
useLibrary 'org.apache.http.legacy'
defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sube.movil"
    minSdkVersion 16
    targetSdkVersion 23
    versionCode 12
    versionName "2.4"
    multiDexEnabled true
}
```

and

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launch"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    tools:replace="android:icon">
    <activity
        android:name="com.sube.movil.SplashScreenActivity"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:noHistory="true">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity
        android:name="com.sube.movil.MainActivity"
        android:label="Sube Movil"
        />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
        android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version"   />
    <meta-data
        android:name="com.google.android.maps.v2.API_KEY"
        android:value="AIzaSyBykfLl1DhKCNaWdpQsCADxHVtrkgs9ZUY" />
</application>
</manifest>
```

Comment: What do you mean by you cannot see. Did you install the Application from Playstore. If not, there is every chance that after upgrade Android did not retain the due to security issues. Did you try to install it after upgrade ?

Comment: Is it that it's not installing, or that it's installing but not showing up in the apps list? Where are you being told it's not compatible?

Comment: @Cheloespinoza It seems you have your app on play store! You are saying  *it is not installing... or that it's installing but not showing* that's two things! if it does not install anyway app is not there.So whats exactly happening ? *tells me that it is not compatible* who? where?

Comment: @Dibzmania I see the application in the play store but it tells me that it is not compatible

Comment: @Charuka It is not compatible with android 6, even though the mindSdkVersion says 16. I see it in my list of apps when I had Lollipop, Now with Marshmallow tells me that my device is not compatible with this version.

Answer (score 0):

Run on **Android 6.0**

> To better optimize your app for devices running Android 6.0, set your
>   targetSdkVersion to "23"

or go for a newer one.

Okay you have done that!

"I have also tried with `buildToolsVersion 23`"

At this one you have 22.0.1. anyway that's up to you.Recommendation is always keep that up to date.Just mentioned that as well.

> Android SDK Build-Tools is a component of the Android SDK required for
>   building Android apps. It's installed in the /build-tools/
>   directory.
>
> You should always keep your Build Tools component updated by
>   downloading the latest version using the Android SDK Manager. By
>   default, the Android SDK uses the most recent downloaded version of
>   the Build Tools. If your projects depend on older versions of the
>   Build Tools, the SDK Manager allows you to download and maintain
>   separate versions of the tools for use with those projects

Finally your issue!

You have some thing like below right?

[image]

Well the answer is I dunno!. But if you want to find out why, Google Play actually tells you.It's just a little bit *hidden*.you can actually click the tiny plus sign next to that message to see why. For example, it might be that your carrier blocks the app, that your phone lack the required version of Android, or something similar. You can also see OS requirements, maturity ratings, and more information along the right hand side.

It isn't a new feature, but if you didn't know it was there, it can be pretty helpful to see.

So go and find that out then you will know why Google Play Shows You Why an App Is Incompatible! Still hard to figure it out? post that Google Play description!

Answer (score 0):

I found the problem, it was a module called CircularReveal, which apparently was only compatible with Lollipop. I removed the module and solved it.